# Having error "got an unexpected keyword argument" and can't fix it

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Good day to everyone, I have been writing a simple bot to delete messages from one group and to forward them to another, so while executing I am facing this error, it says "TeleBot.forward_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chatid'"
I am new to bot making so any help would be appreciated

Here is my code

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('tocken')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi, ready to delete')
    if ':' not in message.text:
        bot.forward_message(chatid='group chat id',
                            fromchatid=message.chat.id, messageid=message.message_id)
        bot.delete_message(chatid=message.chat.id, messageid=message.message_id)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be missmatching the variable's nomenclature.

Based on [PyTelegramBot](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.forward_message) documentation, **forward_message()** expects this params:

> forward_message(chat_id: Union[int, str], from_chat_id: Union[int,
> str], message_id: int, disable_notification: Optional[bool] = None,
> protect_content: Optional[bool] = None, timeout: Optional[int] = None,
> message_thread_id: Optional[int] = None)

So your ***chatid*** should go like ***chat_id*** and the same goes with every other param.

Your snippet would go something like this:

```
bot.forward_message(chat_id='group chat id', from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
```

**Note**: This nomenclature may be version dependant and was described as current latest (4.9.0).